# How to make GXT grid dynamically adds a new new column

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am trying to make a dynamic grid using GXT 3.1.0. I am facing issues in adding a new column.

Can I add/remove grid column header dynamically? If that is complicated or not possible.

Comment: What is the issue? Any specific exception or difficulty ?

Comment: https://github.com/sencha/gxt-demo-grids This seems like what you are looking for

Comment: In data table grid, we have unmodifiable column config in which to add a new column I have to recreate column config which I was avoiding due to performance loss in reloading the complete data table grid. I was seeking for a better option to add a new column in grid.

Comment: What do you mean unmodifiable column config?  You can't do grid.reconfigure()?

Comment: Yes, i have grid.reconfigure() as a workaround. While reconfiguring I have reinitialized whole grid again which lags performance if the grid has a lot of data.

Comment: Can you try to hide/unhide the columns as and when required?

Comment: With hide, unhide columns I have to add extra checks on the binded table. There is also validations going on for the column data. So hiding, unhiding will not be the suitable option. Currently, I am reconfiguring with new column model and list store.